# Dual boot problems after routine upgrade (all the usual solutions tried and failed)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7. GRUB dual boot worked perfectly until I ran `apt-get update`. Since the update it does not.

1. GRUB defaults to the mem test
   When I run `customize-grub`, the first entry is my linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.10-991-generic, and is highlighted. I've saved this configuration and saved it to my MBR, but still grub defaults to the memory test.
2. GRUB doesn't see windows
   I've followed instructions on the web: `os-prober` found windows as it should have, but `update-grub` did not. I ran `boot-repair` and followed instructions, the last of which was `apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub* shim-signed`
   but this returned a `no match`.

Can anybody suggest how to get my windows back and how to default to a linux boot?

```
#fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1796a6c6



  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2           81920     1617919      768000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3   *     1617920   741703679   370042880    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       741703680  1465147391   361721856    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       741705728   766871551    12582912   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       766873600   913674239    73400320   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       913676288  1465147391   275735552   83  Linux

#os-prober
/dev/sda2:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda3:Windows 7 (loader):Windows1:chain

#update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
using custom appearance settings
Found background image: /home/leo/Photos/Yosemite_June09/IMG_1556.JPG
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.10-991-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.10-991-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.0-030400-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.4.0-030400-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.10-991-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.10-991-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.4.0-030400-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.4.0-030400-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic
```

Comment: You have a BIOS boot system as you have MBR partitioning. Do not boot Boot-Repair in UEFI mode.  The signed version is for UEFI boot on gpt partitioned drives, so it should not suggest that in BIOS mode. You also should houseclean old kernels.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but I'm sorry I don't understand at all.    The boot-repair that I have has no options, so I don't understand what not booting Boot-repair in uefi mode means.    Also, I was running boot-repair from the command line, perhaps that was my problem.     by housecleaning old kernels, do you mean, simply erasing them?

Comment: The choice of UEFI or BIOS is only from UEFI/BIOS boot menu. Your flash drive or DVD should have two boot options if UEFI/BIOS is newer and capable of booting either way. The two boot modes are not compatible and once you start booting in one mode you cannot change.

Comment: so, in my bios, I'm currently doing a LEGACY boot, with secure boot off.    I'm offered the choices of UEFI with secure boot on or off.

Comment: That would be correct. With BIOS/legacy/CSM there is no secure boot. And often better for now to have secure boot off. In the future you may want it. Ubuntu will work with secure boot on has it has the same key as Microsoft. But if Windows is in BIOS mode better to also have Ubuntu in BIOS mode.

Comment: So it sounds like I'm correct to boot with LEGACY, but that leaves me with not knowing how to fix this problem.   As noted above, the command that boot-repair advises, i.e., apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub* shim-signed, appears to be broken.    Could you suggest another approach please?    Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Can you boot into Ubuntu or just live installer. Windows not found is probably a Windows issue. Post link to Boot info report that you run from Boot-Repair. I still do not understand why Boot-Repair thinks you want UEFI, or is it trying to uninstall the efi files and convert you to BIOS? Boot-Repair has not been updated for 14.04 and UEFI grub packages changed from grub-efi to grub-efi-amd64 and grub-efi-amd64-signed. grub* should cover all the grub versions, but perhaps the signed is incorrect? And you then want to install grub-pc for BIOS boot.

Comment: I don't have any problems booting into ubuntu.    Here's the boot info report, which finds windows fine and claims that there are no windows errows, making the problem more mystifying.   http://paste.ubuntu.com/8054966/        Don't understand the details about grub, I'm afraid, above my pay-grade.

Comment: Configuration looks ok to me. But grub really only boots working Windows. Have you run sudo update-grub. Otherwise you may have to move boot flag to sda2. You show Windows boot files in both sda2 & sda3, but normal boot usually is from sda2 boot partition. If you did not create a Windows repairCD or flash before install, you may be able to move boot flag to sda2, use Boot-Repair Advanced mode to temporarily reinstall Windows boot loader and use f8 to get into Windows repair console. May require running auto repair 3 times or manual fix. Then reinstall grub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY managed to solve this problem, the solution after all was completely trivial. Using grub-customizer, General settings tab, there was an unchecked box Check for other operating systems Once I checked that and wrote to MBR, all of my problems went away, grub listed linux as the default entry and found windows.

I can only imagine that this flag was set before I did my big upgrade, but the upgrade unchecked the flag for some completely inexplicable reason.

Anyway, thanks oldfred, for your patience.
~

Answer (score 1):

I also have this sort of problem when I upgraded. To solve this you have to boot with help of live CD of ubuntu. Then you have to install boot repair using these commands in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

After installing this you can use `recommend repair` option available in boot repair. If this does not solve you problem then you can further use `advanced options` available in boot repair. Detailed instructions for boot repair can be found here. [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair/)

Comment: Thanks very much for this!     Unfortunately I had problems at every stage.   add-apt-respository seemed to work but http://etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list was not downloaded.   boot-repair was not updated, same problem as before,  apt-get purge -y --force-yes grub* shim-signed but this returned a "no match".     I looked at advanced options, but the threatening advice about making things work scared me off.